# Share buttons in some specific posts in WordPress

Tags: social-sharing

I want to put the option to share (with share buttons in post footer) but just in some specifics posts, and I want to control this in the admin panel.

I know a plugin, but I want do this "without plugin".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`conditional tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

You can hook in a div for [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) using conditional tags and WordPress or theme specific hooks from your functions file.

**Hook Buttons in Using Custom Function**

In this example, [`wp_footer`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer)

```
function wpsites_function() {
if ( is_single(array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ) ) ) {
    echo '<div class="addthis_native_toolbox"></div>';
}}
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpsites_function');
```

Change wp_footer to any other WordPress hook position or theme specific hook.

**Add Code In Template**

You could also add the code with conditional tag directly to your child themes single.php file in the position you want the buttons to display.

**Load Javascript for Buttons**

You'll need to load the js for the AddThis script on every page you want the buttons after you create you own account and use your own publisher i,d in the code.

```
<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-52f6368a531ddc3b"></script>
```

You can do this using [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Or use the Header and Footer scripts box your theme includes.